# Xcode project - sync remote repository from github to Mac

Tags: xcode, git, github

I am working on a project at work and would like to work on it at home as well. I synced the Xcode project to a remote repository to github from my work's mac. I am wondering how I can get a copy on my home's mac and sync it so that I will be able to push commits and pull?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple

```
git clone https://....yourRepositoriy/ongithub
```

You have to run this with git installed from the Terminal

Should work and copy all files to your local machine

Comment: After I run this command, will I be able to push commits to the remote repository as well? And I don't see my .gitignore file in my project folder. Do I need to unhide it?

Comment: Yes the git clone command automatically creates a .git folder that includes all git configuration files. So you were able to push from you new workstation to the remote repository as well.

On my terminal the file is visible. but the default terminal on mac hides the file, you can print the content using: 

`cat .gitignore`

or use nano to edit the file:

`nano .gitignore`